# Docker exec with ssh gives no such container Error

Tags: docker, ssh

I am trying to `ssh` directly into a docker container using the following commands:

```
CONTAINER_ID=`ssh user@host -t "docker ps | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1"`
ssh -tt user@host "docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash"
```

When I do this I get:

```
Error: No such container: <container_id>
```

Even though if I run the `exec` on the instance itself, the container is there, and it does let me connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet that your $CONTAINER_ID contains CRLF characters.
Remove them by using `tr`:

```
CONTAINER_ID=`ssh user@host -t "docker ps | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr -d '\r\n' " `
```

And it should do the trick.

Of course, you'll connect to the first result of `docker ps`, whichever it is...

Comment: This was it. Thanks! I found them using a `hexdump` too.